# Problem with "porting" swift playground code to application in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, type-conversion

I've written some code in swift playground. It works perfectly in console, but when I was "porting" it to a swift project it has some strange errors. Do you know also how to make the calculation appear on the display/UiLabel.

I've debugged it in playground, so it is not issue of the code, but of that how I've setup into an app. Xcode don't show any errors in main.storyboard, while I was not modifying any other part of code yet, but the errors have got "Main.storyboard" below them.
…………………………………………………………………………

//Here is the code, but swift do not show any errors here:

```
import UIKit

//variebles, some of them are for different functions in my app
var credit: Double = 0
var years: Int = 0
var procentage: Double = 0
var overall = 0.0 
var month: Int = 0
var wanted: Double = 0
var bankInterest: Double = 0 
var capitalInterest: Double = 0 
var left: Double = credit 
var interest: Double = 0.0 
var capital: Double = 0.0

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
        weak var creditCalculationOutput: UILabel! //display
        weak var creditInput: UITextField! //textfield
        weak var procentageInput: UITextField! //textfield
        weak var yearsInput: UITextField! //textfield

 //converison UiTextField to Double
    var creditInputConvert :Double? = Double (creditInput.text!)
    var procentageInputConvert :Double? = Double             (procentageInput.text!)
    var yearsInputConvert :Double? = Double (yearsInput.text!)

func creditButton(_ sender: UIButton)                         {

    for month in 1 ... years * 12                   {
        var left = creditInputConvert
        procentage = procentageInputConvert!

        let capital = credit / Double (years * 12)
        let bankInterest = (left! * procentage) / 12.0
        let capitalInterest = capital + bankInterest
        left! -= capital
        overall += capitalInterest
        print("Miesiąc \(month): \(capitalInterest) PLN || [ C: \           (capital) I: \(bankInterest)")

    }
    print("Kredyt wyniesie mnie \(overall)")
}
```

Errors:
Auto Layout Localization: Views without any layout constraints may clip their content or overlap other views. (6 times)
main.storyboard

Configuration: Launch screens may not set custom classnames
main.storyboard

//I' used "//" on the parts that are not code, to make it easier to copy into Xcode

Do you know also how to make the calculation appear on the display/UiLabel?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on storyboards and auto-layout. There are plenty of tutorials out there. Your fields and labels should be connected in Interface Builder, they should look like `@IBOutlet weak var fieldName: UITextField!`.

Comment: Thanks for a clue, definitely I will read up that, but after changing this "weak var creditInput: UITextField!" into this "@IBOutlet weak var creditInput: UITextField" cause an error

Comment: You need to connect the labels and fields on your storyboard with your code, not just add the code directly. You control-drag on the storyboard items to your code, and that associates them. I really recommend some more research first, as you'll get very frustrated when things don't work otherwise!

Comment: Also, your calculation vars aren't optionals as you're forcing the values from the text fields. Just `var percentageInputContent: Double = Double(percentageInput.text!)`. And you don't really need to declare as a Double either, the compiler will figure it out!